# How can I assign an object to a local object in IOS?

Tags: ios, nsobject

Below is my code:

First Category.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Category : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *items;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *description;
    NSString *imagePath;
    NSString *id;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imagePath;
-(id)init;
-(UIImage*)getImage;
@end
```

And the controller:

```
- (id)initWithCategory:(Category *)categoryItem
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.category = categoryItem; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

And in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Category *category;
- (id)initWithCategory:(Category *)categoryItem;
```

I want that self.category and categoryItem would be exactly the same.

Update: I am so sorry, error was not from here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does 'cannot assign it' mean?  Any kind of warning or flag?

Comment: Values are not the same. I want that category object would be categoryItem.

Comment: I don't believe that `category` does not equal `categoryItem` after the assignment in `initWithCategory`. How are you seeing that?

Comment: With the debug. And items has no objects in it, but categoryItem.items has 2 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `category` is a property, then you should use `self.category`.

However, assuming that you have synthesized your property with a backing ivar such as `_category` (`@synthesize category = _category`), then you should refer to the ivar and use `_category` in the init method.